# Collection View data not updating even after setting the data to it Swift 4

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

Inside my CollectionViewController I have a method to fetch the data like this

```
func fetchData(){
    let newsUrl = "http://api.meroschool.com/school/GetArticles?secretkey=1234&schoolCode=AA36&classId=ClassId000000011&pageNumber=1&type=Activities"

    guard let url = URL(string: newsUrl) else {
        return
    }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){(data, response, err) in

        guard let data = data else {return}

        do{
            let newsResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(NewsResponse.self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.newsList = newsResponse.newsList
                print("count", self.newsList?.count)
            }

        }catch let error{
            print("JSON Error", error)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

I have setup all setup for **ViewController** to set the dynamic cells and it works while I set dummy data. But using the above method it is not updating the ViewController even the data are set to the **newsList**.

Some of the questions' answer in web says need to set the data in main thread so I setting data like.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.newsList = newsResponse.newsList
                print("count", self.newsList?.count)
            }
```

But not working for me. What would be the right way to set/update the data that is loaded from API so that CollectionViewController updates.

Comment: You update the data, but never reload the collection view

Comment: what's the way to update the collection view then?

Comment: Call `reloadData()` on your collection view?

Comment: oh yeah it worked. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The collection view doesn't know that you're updated the underlying data source. So you need to state that explicitly by calling `reloadData()`

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in 
                self?.newsList = newsResponse.newsList
                self?.yourCollectioView.reloadData()
            }
```